# Python How to remove a specific element from a txt file

Tags: python, file, txt

Can someone tell me how to remove something from a .txt file using **python**? I remember something like `.truncate()`? I don't know. But please make your code simple and short, I just started learning like 5 months ago. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: `truncate()` can only be used to remove something at the end of the file. If you want to remove from the middle, you have to read through the file, copying to a new file except for the part you want to remove.

Comment: [Python File truncate() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_truncate.htm) ...

Comment: Yeah but what if I want to remove ALL of the existing elements in a text file?